# How to get Detail view of bootstrap html form after submit Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, view

I have a bootstrap form where after filling data its successfully get inserted to database .Now i want to show detail view of form with filled data but it taking me back to create view after submit with data added to database. i guess i have problem with site url. for better understanding hereby i am attaching my code.

my create view file code is :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="job"  action="<?php echo site_url('admission/add_students')?>" method="POST" name="job">
```

where as controllers(admission):

```
     function add_students() {
$this->load->model('admission_detail_model');

    $data=array(
            'student_id'=>'La-0002'.$this->input->post('student_id'),
            'father_name'=>$this->input->post('father_name'),
            'mother_name'=>$this->input->post('mother_name'),
            'fname'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
            'lname'=>$this->input->post('Last_name'),
            'place_of_birth'=>$this->input->post('place_birth'),
            'mother_tounge'=>$this->input->post('mother_tounge'),
            'd_o_b'=>$this->input->post('DOB'),
            'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
            'religion'=>$this->input->post('religion'),
            'sc_st_obc'=>$this->input->post('sc_st_obc'),
            'caste'=>$this->input->post('caste'),
            'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
            'admitting_student'=>$this->input->post('Admit_std'),
            'father_edu_qual'=>$this->input->post('father_q'),
            'mother_edu_qual'=>$this->input->post('mother_q'),
            'annual_income'=>$this->input->post('annual_income'),
            'father_occupation'=>$this->input->post('father_occupation')

            );
        $this->admission_detail_model->add_students($data);
        $this->index();



}
```

Model:

```
class Admission_detail_model extends CI_Model {
    function add_students($data) {
    $this->db->insert('students',$data);
    return; }
```

Everything working fine i just want to add detail view after submit form not another create form View. For detail view i have controller defined in my base controller(admission) :

```
         public function detailed_admission()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('Header');
    $this->load->view('side_menu');


    $this->load->view('admission/detailted_view');

    $this->load->view('footer');


}
```

when i try to replace  site url in create view file

```
"<?php echo site_url('admission/detailted_view')?>"`
```

it does not enter data in database redirect  directly to this view without any data.

This is my first question so if i had made any mistake please avoid it.
Thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my comments in the code.

```
function add_students() {
    $this->load->model('admission_detail_model');
    $data=array(
            'student_id'=>'La-0002'.$this->input->post('student_id'),
            'father_name'=>$this->input->post('father_name'),
            'mother_name'=>$this->input->post('mother_name'),
            'fname'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
            'lname'=>$this->input->post('Last_name'),
            'place_of_birth'=>$this->input->post('place_birth'),
            'mother_tounge'=>$this->input->post('mother_tounge'),
            'd_o_b'=>$this->input->post('DOB'),
            'nationality'=>$this->input->post('nationality'),
            'religion'=>$this->input->post('religion'),
            'sc_st_obc'=>$this->input->post('sc_st_obc'),
            'caste'=>$this->input->post('caste'),
            'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
            'admitting_student'=>$this->input->post('Admit_std'),
            'father_edu_qual'=>$this->input->post('father_q'),
            'mother_edu_qual'=>$this->input->post('mother_q'),
            'annual_income'=>$this->input->post('annual_income'),
            'father_occupation'=>$this->input->post('father_occupation')

            );

    //To insert the record in the database
    $this->admission_detail_model->add_students($data); after 

    //open the detail view page
    // $this->index(); why did you call index function ??

    $this->detailed_admission(); //call detailed function just after the form submission or you can perform redirect('admission/detailed_admission')


}
```

Comment: katiyar Hi now its working fine i just missed that i am loading index function again so i was getting create view. Thanks for your answer it works